# User determined ordering or sorting with php mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

What is the best way to assign orders to mysql table rows? If I have rows 1 to 5 and I want to remove 4, how can I make 5 the new 4? If I make make 3 the new 1, I need to add 1 to each of the other rows. There could be 1 or 2 rows or a hundred.

Is there a simpler way than manually programming each contingency?

Thanks in advance.

additional:
I have an interface where I add packages for customers to see. They are automatically ordered ascending by id. I can reorder them by price, package name, or whatever, but I want to arbitrarily order them by my own preference from time to time.

Thanks again.

Comment: Is the position a unique field in your database or not?

Comment: don't ever reuse primary id's

Comment: @Dagon order doesn't have to be primary

Comment: I added an order field, independent of id, and am about to program it the long way, but hoped someone had a better way.

Comment: sort by ORDER, but don't use the order id in the db as the displayed order counter. or in other words don't mix the logic of data structure with the business requirement of some numbering system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a unique `order_column` column in your database:

**To add a new row at position x:**

- Lock tables
- update all rows where position >= x and add 1
- Then insert the new row at position x
- Unlock tables

**To swap positions x and y:**

- `UPDATE table SET x=(@temp:=x), x = y, y = @temp;`

[(source)](http://beerpla.net/2009/02/17/swapping-column-values-in-mysql/)

**To remove a row at position x:**

- Lock tables
- Remove row at position x
- update all rows where position > x and subtract 1
- Unlock tables

**To display data:**
Just `ORDER BY` by the `order_column` column.

Comment: If you're going to down vote at least tell me what's wrong with my answer.

Comment: This is very well a possible answer to this question (which is unclear).

Comment: Yea, this is the best answer. Thank you for taking the time to point me the right way Mike.

Answer (score 1):

Basic approaches to ordering usually amount to ordering on a specific column either alphabetically or numerically. Alternatively if the the order that you need can not be created based on the data you have then you need to add a column exculisevly for ordering purposes, then create an interface to populate that with data. Sounds like you need to do the later.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I completely misunderstood the question:

Leave the table alone and just use `ORDER BY` to determine sorting when `SELECT`ing rows.